# TFS Database Architecture

Tags: sql-server, database-design, tfs

I am building the backend for an application that will work with the TFS Object Model. So far I have a simple design with two tables. Instead of having a third table for the users, let's say `dbo.Users`, I want to work with the `UserID` column under `dbo.UserPermissions` in the database `Tfs_DefaultCollection`:

UserID: `S-1-5-21-1081711537-3457464029-1495713236-1119`

I am wondering exactly where (which table, in which database) does TFS stores the Active Directory user information? Any advice and pointers towards online documentation on MSDN would be greatly appreciated. My goal is to map a user with a WorkItemID in one of my tables without having to add a new User table.

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't store the user, but instead it adds users to TFS groups.  The User information needs to be pulled from AD.

Comment: In this case, how can I integrate my small database with TFS users and groups?

Comment: @DaveShaw, Yes that was my intent, but we want to create a constraint between a certain column and the authenticated user in the database level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not supported, or recommended to work with the TFS tables directly. Doing so may adversely impact the function and performance of the system. It is also likely that the schema will change in a future version.

However, if you want to go ahead anyway, you will find the `tbl_security_identity_cache` table in your `tfs_configuration` database useful. It is where TFS syncs identities from AD too.